# latexmk full build command from SublimeTex and LatexTools

Tags: latexmk, sublime-text, latextools

I have a document that I've been working on for a long time using Sublime Text 3, LatexTools, and TexLive. Both on Windows 10 and Mac.
Everything there works great.

I tried to compile it from the command line using `latexmk thesis` and `latexmk --shell-escape thesis` but it fails.

It cannot find figure and table files, most likely because I have multiple `\graphicspath` statements, allowing me to show the same charts from multiple directories.

How do I find out the full command line / environment used by Sublime Text / LatexTools so I can run it from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full command line of any commands LaTeXTools uses is logged to the console (in the **View** menu, select **Show Console**).

If you really need the environment variables, they can be gleaned from the information displayed by the **LaTeXTools: Check System** command.

Comment: Thanks - both are correct and helped me build it from cli